# App crashes in iOS 13 when pushing ABPersonViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, addressbookui

Till iOS 12 code is working fine. But the below code is crashing the application on iOS13.

**NOTE:** I do not want to upgrade to Contacts framework right now.

Sharing my code below:

```
ABPersonViewController *vc = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
vc.displayedPerson = person;
vc.addressBook = parser.addressbook;
vc.allowsEditing = YES;
vc.personViewDelegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

When pushing, app crashes only on iOS 13. sharing below crash stack:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CNPropertyNotFetchedException', reason: 'Contact 0x7fb020d2bc70 is missing some of the required key descriptors: (
    "<CNAggregateKeyDescriptor: 0x600003176be0: kind=+[CNContactContentViewController descriptorForRequiredKeys]>"
)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e63127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010deb3b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6310bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Contacts                            0x000000010e03f0fb -[CNContact assertKeysAreAvailable:] + 119
    4   ContactsUI                          0x000000012a2ded30 +[CNContactViewController viewControllerForContact:] + 137
    5   AddressBookUI                       0x000000010df62233 -[ABPersonViewController reloadContactViewController] + 858
    6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113361aca -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 172
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113362277 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00000001132b13dd -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1039
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001132c730c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 698
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001132c8721 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001132a9553 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 217
    12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113ec64bd -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2478
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ee87db1 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 255
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ee8dfa3 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 517
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ee998da _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 80
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ede0848 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEd + 324
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ee15b51 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 643
    18  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113a0a3f4 _afterCACommitHandler + 160
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e593867 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e58e2fe __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e58e97a __CFRunLoopRun + 1514
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e58e066 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000117be9bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001139e0d4d UIApplicationMain + 1621
    25  QA cleanup dupes                    0x000000010bf5ace0 main + 112
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010fb72c25 start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm using AddressBook framework.
Please help me get through this.
Thanks

Comment: please post ABPersonViewController code

Comment: where you are making NSArray *keysToFetch

Comment: @jawadAli That's the class provided by Apple itself in the AddressBookUI framework.

Comment: have you given any keys what you want to fetch from contact ?

Comment: ABPersonViewController is deprecated :)

Comment: @jawadAli Well yes it is, but why is it crashing in iOS13 and not in iOS 12?

Comment: @VaibhavKhatri did you find any solution

Comment: @RaviOjha unfortunately no. I moved my code to new contacts framework.

Answer (score 0):

**AddressBook** and **AddressBookUI** Is deprecated

Better is to shift to

```
 @import Contacts; 
 @import ContactsUI;


-(void)fetchAllContacts:(void(^)(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error))completion
{
    self.contactArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (success)
        {
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactNamePrefixKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey,
                              CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey];

            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];

            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"ERROR IN FETCHING: %@", error.description);
            }
            else
            {
                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts)
                {
                    @try
                    {
                        CMCustomContacts *newContact = [[CMCustomContacts alloc] init];
                        newContact.phoneArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                        newContact.emailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                        newContact.firstName = contact.givenName;
                        newContact.lastName = contact.familyName;

                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                        newContact.profileImage = image;

                        for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers)
                        {
                            NSString *phone = [label.value stringValue];
                            if ([phone length] > 0)
                            {
                                [newContact.phoneArray addObject:phone]; NSLog(@"PHONE NUMBER: %@",phone);
                            }
                        }

                        for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.emailAddresses)
                        {
                            NSString *email = label.value;
                            if ([email length] > 0)
                            {
                                [newContact.emailArray addObject:email];  NSLog(@"EMAIL :: %@",email);
                            }
                        }

                        [self.contactArray addObject:newContact];
                    }
                    @catch (NSException *exception)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"EXCEPTION IN CONTACTS :: %@", exception.description);
                    }
                    @finally
                    {
                        NSLog(@"FINALLY");
                    }
                }

                NSLog(@"COUNT OF CONTACTS :: %lu", (unsigned long)self.contactArray.count);
            }
        }
        completion(granted, error);
    }];
```